# What is the relation between Surreal birth order and its numeric value

Tags: reference-request, modular-arithmetic, surreal-numbers

I found an equation that matches surreal numbers to their birth order. The surreal numbers are born in a sequence, but their numeric values (labels) come in a different order. This equation matches the two orderings.

$$ \large \frac{2 n + 1}{2^{d}}-2 = \frac{s(f-2)}{2^{w+1}} \: \text{mod} \: {2}$$

Where n & v are given...

d = $\lfloor log _{2} \: {n} \rfloor$

w = $\lfloor \left| {v} \right| \rfloor$

f = $\left|v\right| - w$

s = $\large \frac {\left| {v} \right|}{v}$

Symbol meaning:

n = given surreal appearance order or "birth" as a positive integer ($n \in {Z \gt {0}}$)

d = digits in binary representation of order number n

v = given numeric value or "label" ($\text{v} \in \text{dyadic rational or} s(w+f)$)

w = whole value part of absolute v

f = fractional part of absolute v

s = sign of the v

This equation came from a circle for me. I expect that this was already discovered by others. I want to know more about finite dyatic surreals and their creation.

Can someone direct me to the source of information that would provide me with these sorts of equations?

I found the equation like this: https://github.com/peawormsworth/tools/blob/master/surreal_order_value/Birth%20Order%20and%20Label%20Value%20-%20Surreal%20Equality.ipynb

I choose mod 2 because it fits around the unit circle when multiplied by pi i and is raised to e:

[image: corrected tree]
[image: open the canopy]
[image]

Update: I found an answer to my question which allows the value to be directly determined from the order and vice-versa. I  will post an answer when I can transfer the formulas from paper. In the meantime, this is the python code I used to verify the logic:

```
from math import floor, log2, copysign
from fractions import Fraction

def ov(n):
   """given natural n, return the value of the nth surreal number"""
   if n == 0:
      return None
   l = floor(log2(n+1/2))
   r = (2*n+1)/2**l-2
   a = abs(r-1)
   s = copysign(1,r-1)
   w = floor(-log2(1-a))
   f = (a-1)*2**(w+1)+2
   v = Fraction(s*(w+f))
   return v

def vo(v):
   """given dyadic v, return the ordinal of the surreal having value v"""
   if v is None:
      return 0
   u = abs(v)
   s = copysign(1,v)
   w = floor(u)
   f = u-w
   r = Fraction(s*((f/2-1)/2**w+1)+1)
   a = r.numerator
   b = r.denominator
   o = int((a-1)/2+b)
   return o

# testing the first 128 surreal numbers:
for n in range(128):
   print(n,ov(n),vo(ov(n)))
```

Comment: What are $n$, $d$, $s$, $f$, and $w$ in this formula?

Comment: Thanks celtschk. I have updated the variables with meaning. The link provides more detail as well as code and diagrams.

Comment: So if I understand your numbering correctly, it only applies to numbers of finite birthday and can be obtained as follows: Take the sign representation of the surreal number, replace every $+$ by $1$ and every $-$ by $0$, prepend the digit $1$, and interpret the resulting digit string as binary number. Or in reverse: Write the number in binary, remove the leading $1$, replace all other $1$ by $+$ and all $0$ by $-$, and interpret the result as sign representation. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes. I am only considering surreal representation inside a computer, so it's finite as computer calculations. But I don't understand infinity and I can not say what the formula does not apply to. Your description of the equation is very good.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a breadth first traversal of an infinite binary tree, and then are observing the relationship with the numeric values of the dyadics as placed on the tree in the way that arises naturally in constructions of the finite surreals.

I doubt that anyone has written up a similar formula per se, but perhaps the parts that need to be composed have been written up in various places.

Comment: Mark S, I noticed the Surreal binary tree was drawn upside down, so that it did not express clearly the {L|R} relationship between numbers. Many lines were missing. So I added them. Then I notice that the empty sets can be strung together with string and tied to a point and then you pull the string and the tree fans open its branches into a circular canopy. Then all the numbers fit nicely in a circular symmetric pattern. Then I noted the locations of the birth orders and numeric values and wrote unit circle formulas for them and equated them. Maybe I should add a drawing showing where it comes

Comment: Mark S, here is the image of the missing connections from the surreal tree diagram: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peawormsworth/tools/202dee2bd89d8157f5e8ae55c6b6399ed0db60dc/SurrealMandala/images/tree1.jpg
Sorry for pictures and not words. I don't know how to say it mathematically. But all surreal numbers connect upward to only TWO number (the right and left). Although they connect downward to infinite numbers (they are the parent of every number built on top of them). So looking at upward lines going to 0 is a finite and fathomable image, whereas the typical image in wikis is not.

Comment: It seems these diagrams are related to combinatorial properties where you just have the infinite binary tree and just connect things to their parent and their nearest parent-on-the-other-side. The surreals don't really come into play except for the final formula you write down.

Answer (score 1):

Given surreal order number $n$, find surreal value $v$:

$$ l = \lfloor log_{2} (n+ {1 \over 2} ) \rfloor $$

$$ r = {2n+1 \over 2^l} -3  $$

$$ m = | r | $$

$$ s = {r \over m} $$

$$ w = \lfloor -log_{2} (1-m) \rfloor  $$

$$ f = 2^{ w+1 }( m-1 ) $$

$$ v=s(w+f) $$

... value $v$ has been found from order $n$

Given surreal value $v$ find surreal order $n$:

$$ u = |v|  $$

$$ s = {v \over u} $$

$$ w = \lfloor u \rfloor  $$

$$ f=u-w $$

$$ r = s \left ( {{f \over 2} - 1 \over 2^{w}} + 1 \right ) $$

let..

$$ {a \over b} = r + 1  $$

$$ n = {a-1 \over 2} + b  $$

... order $n$ has been found from value $v$

Finding a and b in the $2^{nd}$ to last equation should not be difficult. $r + 1$ is a dyadic rational between 0 and 2 so $a$ will be a positive odd, $b$ will be a power of two and $a < 2b$.

$n$ is the $n^{th}$ surreal number born where $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, a natural number (0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

$v$ is the value of the surreal number $ v \in base2 $

$r$ is a fraction between -1 and +1. Specifically $ r \in dyadic, |r| < 1 $. It can be plotted around the unit circle as $x$ using $ e^{x \cdot i \cdot \pi} $. Allowing the base2 numbers and the surreal order to be observed over top of one another, like the diagrams posted in the question. However, the circle points here will be rotated 180 degrees from the diagrams above.

In all formulas, $w$ is the absolute whole amount of the value of the surreal number referenced. $f$ is the remaining absolute fractional portion of the value. $s$ is the sign of the value of the surreal number.

I believe this is a correct solution because python code using these formulas correctly converts between surreal number order and value.